# Why is mongo not available on cloudfoundry.com yet available on micro cloud foundry?

Tags: mongodb, cloud-foundry

I built a cache service using mongo, and developed it locally with Micro Cloud Foundry. When I went to deploy, I discovered cloudfoundry.com doesn't offer mongo. Any tips on why this is the case?

```
retina:repository gturnquist$ vmc -v
vmc 0.5.0
retina:repository gturnquist$ vmc info --all
Getting runtimes... OK
Getting frameworks... OK
Getting services... OK

VMware's Cloud Application Platform

target: http://api.cloudfoundry.com
  version: 0.999
  support: http://support.cloudfoundry.com

user: *******************

runtime   description
java      1.6.0_24   
java7     1.7.0_04   
node      0.4.12     
node06    0.6.8      
node08    0.8.2      
ruby18    1.8.7p357  
ruby19    1.9.2p180  

framework    description
grails       
java_web     
lift         
node         
play         
rack         
rails3       
sinatra      
spring       
standalone   

service      version   provider   description                  
blob         0.51      core       Blob store                   
mysql        5.1       core       MySQL database               
postgresql   9.0       core       PostgreSQL database (vFabric)
rabbitmq     2.4       core       RabbitMQ message queue       
redis        2.2       core       Redis key-value store        
redis        2.4       core       Redis key-value store        
redis        2.6       core       Redis key-value store
```

Answer (score 1):

The provisioning of new Mongo databases has been stopped until 10gen fix the recent vulnerability that allows remote shell commands. Should be a couple of days or so.

Answer (score 0):

mongo is currently available on micro cloud foundry, check it here: http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/running/micro_cloud_foundry/

You can run a 256Mb max size db per instance.

Regards,
Moacy